# Change values of a list of list (of tuples) in a for statement

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I want to create an object to store the positions of some creatures of a game.

A list of lists of tuples seemed appropriate to me. The matrix created by the list of lists represents the board of the game, element of it being a tuple of 2 variables ('type', number). For example: ('h', 3) would mean: 'there are 3 humans here'.

So here is how I initialize the board:

```
>>>lines = 5
>>>columns = 5
>>>board= [[(0,0)]*lines]*columns
>>>pprint(board)
[[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]]
```

Then I want to put some humans in my board:

```
>>> board[2][2]=('h',3)
```

I expect the board to be:

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), ('h', 3), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]]
```

but instead, when I do `>>> pprint(board)`, it returns:

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 0), ('h', 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), ('h', 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), ('h', 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), ('h', 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
[(0, 0), (0, 0), ('h', 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]]
```

I don't understand why all the elements of `board` are modified, this is very very frustrating. I am certainly missing something here, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following:

```
board = [[(0,0)]*lines]*columns
```

should become

```
board = [[(0,0)]*lines for _ in range(columns)]
```

Otherwise the top-level list consists of references *to the same sublist*:

```
In [7]: lines = 3

In [8]: columns = 4

In [9]: board = [[(0,0)]*lines]*columns

In [10]: map(id, board)
Out[10]: [18422120, 18422120, 18422120, 18422120]
```

In this setup, when you change one sublist, they all change.

Comment: Wow, that was fast ! Thanks !